# Field is not removed from 'field_config_instance'

Tags: entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean Deleted Field from Database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38328/clean-deleted-field-from-database)

Why the record about deleted field still exists in  'field_config_instance' only status 'deleted' = 1 ? But from 'field_config' records about field removed completely.

```
function mymodule_uninstall() {

  field_attach_delete_bundle('spproduct' , 'spproduct' );
  field_delete_field('field_spproduct_image');
  field_purge_batch(10);
}
```

I wont to remove field from all entity types wherevere it is used and from tables.

Comment: after cron run, records still in table althgough they have 'deleted' = 1 .

Comment: This is still a known issue https://www.drupal.org/node/1351506

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a fair amount of data, you'll need to allow cron to run a few times, or else do a larger batch purge

[field_purge_batch](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_purge_batch/7)(10)

Will only delete 10 records.

> $batch_size: The maximum number of field data records to purge before
>   returning.

Comment: No, this is a test site and only a few post are.